# Got black colour while convert full scroll view content to bitmap

Tags: android, scrollview, android-bitmap

I am trying to convert the `scrollView` to jpg when clicking `ImageView`. It converts only the view that is visible, not the full content. If I manually put 2500 value for `totalHeight` no change it gives only current view with black colour for extra size.

```
shareEstimation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                ScrollView structureEstimation = findViewById(R.id.structure_estimate);
                View u = StructureResult.this.findViewById(R.id.structure_estimate);

                int totalWidth = structureEstimation.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
                int totalHeight = structureEstimation.getChildAt(0).getHeight();


                Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(u, totalHeight, totalWidth);
                //Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(u, 2500, totalWidth);

                String root = getFilesDir().toString();
                String fname = "Estimation.jpg";
                File file = new File(root, fname);


                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    //MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), AUTHORITY, file), "image/*");
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), AUTHORITY, file));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
            }
        });
```

And this is my layout pattern

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout/>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ScrollView recycles data as it scrolls, it does not have entire data , that's why you are getting only currently visible part of `view`. So instead of getting data from `ScrollView` get it from source itself.

Comment: I am completely newbie, suggest any example for getting data from the source and create a form to share.

Comment: "By getting data from source itself", I mean that there must be some other layout(root layout) in your layout xml file which you must have added as child in `ScrollView`. Or you may add your layout file, then source can be clearly pointed.

Comment: @RishbhDhawan I try to convert my root layout(RelativeLayout) but getting the same error.

Comment: `int totalHeight = structureEstimation.getChildAt(0).getHeight();`                              `Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(u, totalHeight, totalWidth);`
 You have to do it for all views in your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: My issue was solved. Thank You @RishabhDhawan

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. am geting height from scrollview, view from linearlayout(child of scrollview)

```
ScrollView structureEstimation = findViewById(R.id.structure_estimate);
View u = StructureResult.this.findViewById(R.id.strct_layout);
int totalWidth = structureEstimation.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
int totalHeight = structureEstimation.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(u, totalHeight, totalWidth);
```